# Relationship between random numbers

Tags: algorithm, numbers, sequence, series

If i have a set of randomly generated numbers (integers), how do I find
a relationship between them so as to express them as a finite sequence and develop an 
algorithm that can generate any nth term of the sequence given some seed data. 
Is there any existing algorithm or framework or library that does such and if there isnt, 
any suggestions on how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: How can there be any relationship between them? If there was then they would not be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm used to generate the (pseudo-random) numbers. If you want to predict future terms, you need some number of past terms *and* the algorithm used. If the algorithm is cryptographically secure, then you are out of luck. If it isn't, then you have a good chance of working out future terms.

I asked [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/predicting-values-from-a-linear-congruential-generator) regarding linear congruence generators (commonly used for simple applications) a while ago. It gives a pretty good discussion of how to predict terms for that class of generator.